# Creating a Slice that contains a map

Tags: go, maps, slice

I'm trying to create a data structure that includes a slice containing a map. This is what I have:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{"Offset": "0", "Properties": []string{}, "Category": "all", "Locations": []string{}, "Accounts": "100" }
```

I need the "properties" element to include a map that looks like this:

```
{"key": "Type", "value": "User"}
```

This seems to be harder than it should be, or maybe I'm just being stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be what you want ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/z5qtuEJPiK))

```
data := map[string]interface{}{"Offset": "0",
    "Properties": map[string]string{
        "key":   "Type",
        "value": "User",
    },
    "Category":  "all",
    "Locations": []string{},
    "Accounts":  "100",
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a map rather than a slice. I need to marshal it to JSON that looks like this: {
"Locations": [],
"Dates": [],
"Properties": [
  {
    "key": "Type",
    "value": "User"
  }
 ],
 "Category": "all",
 "Accounts": [],
 "Offset": 0,
 "Limit": 100
}

Comment: It looks like what you want is a map within a slice. If that's the case, `Properties` should be declared as `[]map[string]string` or phonetically, a slice of maps of strings to strings.